# Having problems after getting data from form and submiting to mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

When i retreive data from form and when i need to submit that data in mysql database, I get some errors. I know that the problem is in `'` and `"` characters

My php code for submiting data :

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO news (id,name)
VALUES ("$id","$name")';
```

Variable `$name` is retreived from form. `$name= $_POST["name"];`

So, if variable `$name` has value of

```
<p>
<span style="color: rgb(68, 68, 68); font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 26.672px;">1. Some text for example</span><br>
</p>
```

How I can query that text when there are problems between `'` and `"`

Comment: where your post code !

Comment: Your original SQL will be interpreted as "INSERT INTO news (id,name)
VALUES ("$id","$name")". Try something like this, `$sql = "INSERT INTO news (id,name) VALUES ('$id','$name')"`. You should probably consider preparing and binding your variables instead.

Comment: what's the value of $name ?

Answer (score 1):

> The difference between using [single quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) and double quotes in php is that if we use single quotes in echo statement then it is treated as a string. If we use variables inside single quotes then it will output as it is variable name.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO news (id,name)
VALUES ($id,'$name')";
```

Since `$name` is a string, its better to write the code in this manner.

> I know that the problem is in ' and " characters. // from question

I hope ,now you know where the problem is .

---

### Update

Now as our friends said in the comment section , to avoid [sql injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work/332367#332367) , One of several ways is by using **prepared Statements with mySQLi**

Using Above method your code will be like below .

```
$name = $_GET['username'];
$id = $_GET['id'];

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_users (id, name) VALUES (?, ?)")) {

    // Bind the variables to the parameter as strings. 
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $id, $name);

    // Execute the statement.
    $stmt->execute();

    // Close the prepared statement.
    $stmt->close();

}
```

**For more** [check here](http://www.wikihow.com/Prevent-SQL-Injection-in-PHP)

Great references by **RiggsFolly**,

[SQL injection that gets around mysql_real_escape_string()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)

http://bobby-tables.com/
**really awesome , thanks  RiggsFolly**

Comment: You dont need the `.` concateation in that query `$sql = "INSERT INTO news (id,name) VALUES ($id,'$name')";` will do just fine

Comment: This is also open to [SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Wrong, so wrong... 
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)

Comment: Please do not go around telling people to use code that leaves them open to a SQL injection attack. Many visitors are too inexperienced to know the difference and will use the code blindly.

Answer (score 1):

how about this ?

```
if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,"INSERT INTO news(id,name) values (?,?)") ){     //$con = mysqli_connect(...
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'ss',$id,$name); // id and name as string
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
```